# Fetching article title and other information automatically in appendix

Tags: article, appendix

I am writing a paper using `article` class. The paper has a lengthy appendix at the end and it should have the title "Appendix to Paper Title", author name and date. Until this point this is what I do -- for the main article, I have this code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\title{A Model of Something}
\author{Somebody\\University of Somewhere}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
```

For the appendix at the end of the paper, I use this:

```
\newpage
\appendixpagenumbering
\appendix
\section*{\centering{\textsc
{Online Appendix (Not for Publication)}}\\[0.6cm]
A Model of Something\\[0.6cm]
Somebody\\[0.6cm]
University of Somewhere\\[0.6cm]
\today}
\section{Derivation of FOCs}
```

My question is -- is there a way to automate this? Is there a way I can use a block of `LaTeX` code that fetches the title, author and date information in appendix from the beginning of the article so that I don't have to do this manually every time when I write a new draft or when I have to manually change the article name in appendix whenever I change the name of the article at the beginning of the document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outside of the tilepage an easy soltuion is the `authoraftertitle` package. It allows for the commands `\MyTitle`, `\MyDate` and `\MyAuthor` to acces the variables.
A full minimall accsample derived of your code can be found above.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{authoraftertitle} % <-- import the package here!

\title{A Model of Something}
\author{Somebody-University of Somewhere}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}

\newpage
\appendixpagenumbering
\appendix
\section*{\centering{\textsc
{Online Appendix (Not for Publication)}}\\[0.6cm]
\MyTitle\\[0.6cm]            % <-- Acces the title variable!
\MyAuthor\\[0.6cm]           % <-- Acces the author variable!
University of Somewhere\\[0.6cm]
\MyDate}                     % <-- Acces the date variable!
\section{Derivation of FOCs}
- \MyAuthor \\               % <-- Acces the title variable!
- \MyDate \\                 % <-- Acces the author variable!
- \MyTitle                   % <-- Acces the date variable!
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am getting "There's no line here to end." error when I use the code with @ sign and within \makeatletter and \makeatother environment and it points to the line where \@date appears. This happens even when I just copy your code and and run it without adding anything. What might be going wrong?

Comment: For me it compiles if I remove `\appendixpagenumbering`

Comment: @NameVergessen, thanks. The new solution with `authoraftertitle` package worked. I have a small problem, though. When I use `\author` command in document preamble, I add a footnote with it containing email, website and office address. I wish to omit this footnote when I use `\MyAuthor` command in the appendix since those details were already listed on article title page. Any way to do this?

Comment: @VKahn No good Idear. Possibly by adding the the foodnote dirctly on the tiltepage. But I have no experiance with that.